# In scheme how do you add an element to a list a certain number of times?

Tags: list, scheme, racket, list-manipulation

so the function would take 3 elements a number item and a list. I want to add the item to the list how ever many times the number says so if i did (pad-front 3 'a '(b c)) it would return (a a a b c) as the list. I think i would want to cons the item to the list and just do that n times im just not sure on how to get it to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Racket this is easy using built-in procedures:

```
(define (pad-front n x lst)
  (append                   ; append together both lists
   (build-list n (const x)) ; create a list with n repetitions of x
   lst))                    ; the list at the tail

(pad-front 3 'a '(b c))
=> '(a a a b c)
```

... But I guess you want to implement it from scratch. The idea is the same as above, but using only primitive procedures; I'll give you some hints so you can figure out the details. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (pad-front n x lst)
  (if <???>            ; base case: if `n` is zero
      <???>            ; then return the tail list
      (cons <???>      ; else cons the element to be repeated
            (pad-front ; and advance the recursion
             <???>     ; subtract one unit from `n`
             x lst)))) ; pass along `x` and `lst`
```

Notice that the trick is to keep adding the `x` element until no more repetitions are needed (in other words: until `n` is zero). At that point, we just stick the tail list at the end, and we're done!

Comment: thank you so much idk what i was thinking before but thank you.